# Navigating in spring URL

Tags: java, spring, url

I have a question regarding navigation.

Currently this is my URL

```
http://localhost:8080/spring/Account/ump
```

I would like to navigate to

```
**http://localhost:8080/spring/Scheduler/test**
this is the URL i am trying to hit but i cannot find the correct ahref code to achieve
```

My Code

```
<li><a href="/Scheduler/test">test page</a></li>
```

I have tried alternatives such as

```
<li><a href="redirect:/Scheduler/test">test page</a></li>
```

The result would be

```
http://localhost:8080/Scheduler/test
```

and for the redirect result it will be

```
redirect:/Scheduler/test
```

I use a InternalResourceViewResolver if it matters.

Comment: @ali786 i cannot obtain the URL http://localhost:8080/spring/Scheduler/test which i would like to achieve.

Comment: you are getting this url http://localhost:8080/Scheduler/test am i correct

Comment: @ali786 Nope i am trying to get this but i am not getting it with all my code.

Comment: give /spring/Schedular/test <li><a href="/Spring/Scheduler/test">test page</a></li>

Comment: change from `/Scheduler/test` to `Scheduler/test`

Comment: @ali786 is there a shorter path? if thats the case i would have to copy and paste the project name for all the URLs. It does not work also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use JSTL on your pages, use the c:url tag which is defined in the core JSTL. The url tag always appends the actual context path to the start of the url.

example:

```
<li>
   <a href="<c:url value='/Scheduler/test'/>">test page</a>
</li>
```

Comment: i am able to use JSTL. but may i know what would be the url ?

Comment: You just need the navigation url not the actual context path, cause c:url appends the context path to the start.